# asp.net: (c# client-side) how to access html element created after page loads?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, pageload

Imagine this,

Step 1: ASPX Page Loads.
Step 2: Button fires a script that creates a html element (div, span, etc) with an id or class tag, including runat server attribute.

and my problem is,

**Final Step: *From my C# file, how to access that element and get it's inner html, so I can save it to a string?***

PS: i'll use that string to save it in my mssql database.

Comment: Did you check `Request.Form`, is your concerned id found there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot create a "real" runat=server element/control without doing a full postback to the server.

The best approach may be to write some script that stores the innerHTML into an ASP.Net hidden field right before you submit the page.  You can then access the value of this hidden field to grab the data.

If you're wanting to dynamically create multiple objects, you'll need to use standard html hidden input fields instead, since you can't create asp.net server controls via javascript.

```
<input type="hidden" name="fieldData_1" value="control 1 html content">
<input type="hidden" name="fieldData_2" value="control 2 html content">
```

You'll then be able to access these hidden fields from the Request.Form object:

```
Request.Form["fieldData_1"]
```

Knowing this, you can now iterate over the form data and process all of your dynamic fields

```
foreach (string fieldData in Request.Form)
{
    if(fieldData.Contains("fieldData_"){
        //process the data for each field
    }
}
```

It is also possible to avoid using hidden fields all together and just pass your data to the server directly using the __doPostback('', '') method.  This could be implemented in many different ways, so I'll just refer you to http://dopostback.net to read up on how the method works.

Comment: I think that will solve my problem, but what if my elements are too many, like a lots of rows in a html table? and I need to pick one row by one and save the fields?

Comment: We do this with our content management system.  We need to dynamically add many elements to the page and store the content on post back.  To accomplish this, instead of using an asp.net hidden control, dynamically create standard html hidden controls (<input type="hidden" name="uniqueName" value="yourValue") and add them to the document and give them all a unique name (not just an id) property.  Then on the server side, you can access these through the Request.Params["fieldName"] object.

Comment: You might want to give each field a common prefix so you can iterate over the Request.Params object and process each of your new hidden fields.

Answer (score 0):

Add `runat="server"` attribute to the tag to make it HTML Control and can be accessible from .cs file by its ID

Comment: I have mention that I'm using runat="server" attribute. But my C# will try to access that element on page load, and if that element is created after the page loads, my C# code will fail and get stucked at page loads.

Comment: Okey Did you add the HTML Control to Page using `Page.Controls.Add(ControlID);`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to post the element inner HTML back to the server. What I would do, in a client function, get the inner HTML of the newly created element, store it in a hidden field, then call `__doPostBack('<hidden element id>', '');`

Comment: I really think your answer and @bgolson will solve my problem, I'll try it. I never worked with __doPostBack(), but I'm going to search about it. But in theory I need to save my info in a hidden field, my problem is that I'll have a lots of elements, like table rows to save, which are created after page loads.