# I need to get all child div elements from div parent in asp code bhind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have div container:

```
<div id="editkomaDiv" ondrop="dropRoom(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" runat="server"></div>
```

that add divs in JS and in ASP I need all divs add

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="NameKomaCurrent" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <select id="Select1">
        <option>בחר קומה</option>
    </select>
    <%--מעטפת לכיתות כדי שלא יהו כיתות בחוץ--%>
    <div class="maatefet"> 
    <div id="editkomaDiv" ondrop="dropRoom(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" runat="server"></div>
   </div>

    <div id="roomsConteiner"  >
        <div  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="roomClass" style="position:absolute; background-color: #cae4f7; top:459px; left: 75px; width:200px;height:100px;"  runat="server">הכיתה</div>
        <div  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="officeClass" style="position:absolute;background-color: #e1dada; top:467px; left: 610px; width:200px;height:100px;" runat="server">משרד</div>
        <div  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="bathroomClass" style="position:absolute;background-color: #fec9a4; top: 462px; left: 348px; width:200px;height:100px;" runat="server">שרותים</div>
    </div>
    <div id="IconsConteiner">
        <img src="../images/airIcon.jpg"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" />
        <img src="../images/LigthIcon.png"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2" />
        <img src="../images/ElectricityIcon.png"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag3" />

    </div>
    <br /><br /><br />  <br /><br /><br />  <br /><br /><br />
    <img src="../images/Garbage.jpg" style="height: 113px; width: 113px"  ondrop="DeleteObj(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"/><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
  <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server"  Text="ooo"  OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hideCountRoom" runat="server" />

</form>

function dropRoom(ev) {

ev.preventDefault();
var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
//יצירת חדר חדש בקומה
var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
//אם זה חדר שקיים בקומה אז רק להעתיק לו מיקום
if (document.getElementById(data).parentElement.id == "editkomaDiv") 
    {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        document.getElementById(data).style.left = ((ev.pageX / window.innerWidth) * 100 - (($("#roomClass")[0].clientWidth / 2) / window.innerWidth) * 100) + "%";
        document.getElementById(data).style.top = ((ev.pageY / window.innerHeight) * 100 - (($("#roomClass")[0].clientHeight / 2) / window.innerHeight) * 100) + "%";
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
    else if (nodeCopy.localName == "div") {
        countroom++;
        //var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();

        //var clickX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
        //var clickY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
        ////הוספת תיבת טקסט לכיתה
        //alert(clickX + "   ======   " + clickY);
        $("<input class='inputromeName' name='name'  type='text' id='" + countroom + "' maxlength='20' placeholder='הכנס שם'>").appendTo(nodeCopy);
        nodeCopy.id = "Id" + countroom;
        nodeCopy.draggable = true;

        nodeCopy.allowDrop = true;
        nodeCopy.ondrop = function (ev) {
            //ארוע של הנחתת תמונה
            //כאן אפשר לבדוק אם קיים כזה איקון כבר
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
            var ImgCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
            if (ImgCopy.localName == "img") {
                ImgCopy.id = "newId";
                ImgCopy.draggable = false;

                ev.target.appendChild(ImgCopy);
            }
        };

////or $(this).offset(); if you really just want the current element's offset
        //מיקום החדר בקומה באחוזים לא מדויק 100 אחוז
        nodeCopy.style.left = ((ev.pageX / window.innerWidth) * 100 - (($("#roomClass")[0].clientWidth / 2) / window.innerWidth) * 100) + "%";
        nodeCopy.style.top = ((ev.pageY / window.innerHeight) * 100 - (($("#roomClass")[0].clientHeight / 2) / window.innerHeight) * 100) + "%";
        ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
    }
}

  protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    editKomadiv.??????????
  }
```

Comment: You need? Well then code it. Or format your code correctly and add a question that can be answered. See [howto-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal complete verifyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what you tried. whats the expected result and what you got and why you are unstatisfied by it.

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10579107/4228458).

Comment: Your divs don't exist server-side. Perhaps explain what your end goal is and why you want to do this, perhaps there's a better way to achieve your objective.